# How to drop an in-memory table in dolphindb?

Tags: database, function, sql-drop, dolphindb

In dolphindb,I can create an in-memory table in dolphindb like:
t = table(1 2 3 as id);
And I can use sql statements at it.
But I don't know the right way to delete it.The function

---

### dropTable(dbHandle, tableName)

can only drop the table in database..
And the function

---

### drop(X, n)

can only drop some rows of the table X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DolphinDB, you can use [undef](http://www.dolphindb.com/help/undef.html) to release variables or function definitions from the memory. A in-memory table like: t = table(1 2 3 as id) can be deleted in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the function clear!().for a  example,

clear!(t)

Comment: The function `clear!` delete all rows of a table. But it doesn't drop the table